# 19.10 seems to have broken suspend on my MB Pro

Tags: suspend, power-management, 19.10

I upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 and now my MacBook Pro won't suspend properly. It's an old 2010 MBP, was working fine before.

If I close the lid, it appears to sleep, but the sleep light on the front stays solid, instead of 'breathing'. When I open the lid, the light goes off but the screen stays black. I have to hold down the power button to kill it and reboot. Same happens if I press the power button when it's set to suspend.

I also noticed I can't restart or shut down from the menu on the login screen - it just does nothing.

Any clues where I can look to fix? It's a fairly vanilla install really. Only power related thing I installed was fan control.

Comment: Both sound as bugs to me.

Comment: This question's closure [is being discussed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18860/why-do-valid-questions-get-closed-without-providing-any-help) and a solution (or workaround) for the sleep problem [has been proposed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18860/why-do-valid-questions-get-closed-without-providing-any-help#comment40404_18861).